# Como leer una respuesta JSON de AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

qué tal? Veran, estoy aprendiendo ajax y json; mientras hacia unas pruebas me ha surgido una duda que no he podido aclarar y me gustaría que me ayudaran.

Les explico:
Tengo un código donde realizo una petición ajax para traerme de la base de datos cierta información. La respuesta la recibo en formato json, y deseo mostrar esa información en un div con id = resultado.

Actualmente tengo esto:

Archivo Empresa.php

```
       require_once "../../model/Conexion.php";

       class Empresa {

       public function __construct(){
                         }

        public function Num_Empresa(){
        global $conexion;
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) as CantidadEmpresas FROM empresa";
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
                             }
                }
```

Archivo EmpresaController.php

```
        require_once "../Modelos/Empresa.php";

         $objEmpresa = new Empresa();

         $data = Array();

         $query_list = $objEmpresa->Num_Empresa();

         if ($query_list) {

         while ($resp = $query_list->fetch_object()) {
         $data[] = array("Cantidad"=>$resp->CantidadEmpresas);

                         }

            echo json_encode($data);
                    } else {
                   echo "error";
                  }
```

Archivo Ajax.js

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
         mostrar_Cantidad_Empresas ();
          });

          function mostrar_Cantidad_Empresas () {

            _ajax("../Controllers/EmpresaController.php", "")
             .done( function (info) {

             console.log(info); 

             var cantidad = JSON.parse(info); 

             console.log(cantidad); 
             var mostrar = "<p> La cantidad de Empresas es: " +//el resultado debería estar aquí. +"</p>"; 

               $("#resultado").html(mostrar); //aqui mostramos el resultado.

              });
                 }

              function _ajax(url, data) {

              var ajax = $.ajax({
              "method" : "POST",
               "url" : url,
               "data" : data
                })

               return ajax;
                }
```

Archivo main.php

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!-- Bootstrap -->
          <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <!-- Font Awesome -->
           <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <!-- NProgress -->
           <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <!-- iCheck -->
           <link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>

            <body class="nav-md">
            <div class="container body">
             <div id="resultado">

             </div>
               <script src="js/ajaxScript/Ajax.js"></script>
             </body>
             </html>
```

Al consultar la consola, tengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como verán, si estoy recibiendo la respuesta. Pero cuando he intentado acceder a la cantidad, por medio de la consola me aparece undefined. De qué forma podria acceder a esos datos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad se llama `Cantidad` en mayúsculas, y no en minúsculas. Tu código debe poner:

```js
var cantidad = [
  {
    Cantidad: "2",
  },
];
var mostrar = "<p> La cantidad de Empresas es: " + cantidad[0].Cantidad + "</p>";
console.log(cantidad);
console.log(mostrar);
```

Comment: Toda la razón. Mil Gracias! Me ha servido.

Answer (score 0):

Tu Json es un array de objetos.  Para desplegar la cantidad debes hacerlo asi:

```
var mostrar = "<p> La cantidad de Empresas es: " + cantidad[0].cantidad;
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo undefined.